# Migrate from old to new PHP

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have an old webpage that works with php5.3, and Im trying to run it in a test enviroment with php5.5 and everything is broken X)

I realized the php tags start just with `<?` instead of `<?php`, adding the php to the tag seemed to fix some of the issues, however now Im having a pretty weird one

*Notice: Undefined variable: Id in C:\xampp\htdocs\ekey\register.php on line 175
Error en: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1*

Originally I was trying to get the variable Id from the session state ID (That works in the actual site with php 5.3) but in my test enviroment with php 5.5 Im getting

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['LOGIN_STATE_ID']) && ($_SESSION['LOGIN_STATE_ID'] > 0))   
     $Id=10;
     //$Id=$_SESSION['LOGIN_STATE_ID'];
     $sql='SELECT * FROM tbl_members WHERE member_id ='. $Id;
     $rs=mysql_query($sql)      or die("MYSQL Error: " . mysql_error());;
     $row=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
     $member_first_name=$row["member_first_name"]; 
     $member_last_name=$row["member_last_name"]; 
     $member_email_id =$row["member_email_id"]; 
     $member_country =$row["member_country"]; 
     $member_state=$row["member_state"]; 

 ?>
```

So as a test I decided to define the variable manually to 10 just before using it....and I still get the same error!!!

And if you were going to ask, Im pretty sure its the php version, Im running another XAMP with php 5.3 and the site in that test enviroment works just nicely!

I would also appreciat any other experiences or tips of migration from 5.3 to 5.5

Comment: Where is your mysql_connect please google how to connect to a mysql database in php.

Comment: The obligatory note: The `mysql_*` functions are becoming deprecated and will be removed in future versions of PHP. You should change your code to use [mysqli](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score -1):

You are missing brackets.

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['LOGIN_STATE_ID']) && ($_SESSION['LOGIN_STATE_ID'] > 0))   
{
     $Id=10;
     //$Id=$_SESSION['LOGIN_STATE_ID'];
     $sql='SELECT * FROM tbl_members WHERE member_id ='. $Id;
     $rs=mysql_query($sql)      or die("MYSQL Error: " . mysql_error());;
     $row=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
     $member_first_name=$row["member_first_name"]; 
     $member_last_name=$row["member_last_name"]; 
     $member_email_id =$row["member_email_id"]; 
     $member_country =$row["member_country"]; 
     $member_state=$row["member_state"]; 
}
?>
```

Right now the `if` statement only affects the following line, `$Id=10`. When the statemant is false `$Id` is not set and your SQL query has an error because it ends with `member_id=`.

Comment: Sql connection is not established.

Comment: @user1613360 If that were the case the error would be: `Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established`. The connection is established, there is just an error in the query. Most probably because of the undefined variable.

Comment: #Gerald First php checks for syntax errors then it checks for logical errors so adding braces will not be enough for the code posted by the user to run.Anyways what you pointed out is right and I missed that.

Comment: The error posted by the OP states that the undefined variable is in line 175. I assume that somewhere in the previous 173 lines an SQL connection is established.

Comment: It is stablished previously, Ill try the brackets and I'll see if that fixes it, but I THINK I had already tried that (I wasnt sure i php 5.3 used brackets, as later on in the code I saw some snipets with "endif"